# How to restore Mysql database from backup in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, dropbox-api

I am trying to add a database restore feature to my application based on `Laravel` but don't know exactly where to start?

**What I just Tried So Far**

```
//restore database from backup
            public function restore($file_name)
            {
                try {
                    
                    $DB_HOST = env("DB_HOST", "");
                    $DB_DATABASE = env("DB_DATABASE", "");
                    $DB_USERNAME = env("DB_USERNAME", "");
                    $DB_PASSWORD = env("DB_PASSWORD", "");
                    $connection = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_DATABASE);
    
                    $file = config('backup.backup.name') . '/' . $file_name;
                    $disk = Storage::disk(config('backup.backup.destination.disks')[0]);
                    if ($disk->exists($file)) {
                        $fs = Storage::disk(config('backup.backup.destination.disks')[0])->getDriver();
                        
                        $handle = fopen($file, "r+");
                        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
                        $sql = explode(';', $contents);
                        $flag = 0;
                        foreach ($sql as $query) {
                            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                            if ($result) {
                                $flag = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        fclose($handle);
                    } else {
                        abort(404, "The backup file doesn't exist.");
                    }
                   
                    if ($flag) {
                        Toastr::success('Operation successful', 'Success');
                        return redirect()->back();
                    } else {
                        Toastr::error('Operation Failed', 'Failed');
                        return redirect()->back();
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    Toastr::error('Operation Failed', 'Failed');
                    return redirect()->back();
                }
            }
```

I am using A [flysystem driver](https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox) for Dropbox that uses the v2 API to backup my database to Dropbox.

Comment: perhaps you could use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-db-snapshots

Comment: @Snapey Thanks for the suggestion but my backups are in Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

I made use of https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php `Mysqldump` class which has a restore method that does not try and execute command line mysql, which many other solutions do.

With `$file` being full dump of the DB:

```php
$mysqldump = new Mysqldump('mysql:host=...', $username, $password);
Artisan::call('db:wipe',['--database' => $connection, '--drop-views' => true]);
$mysqldump->restore($file);
```